# Is there a way to reduce the time spent on migrating the jQuery & bootstrap versions used across the site?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

My client wants to upgrade the jQuery and bootstrap version used on our site to the latest versions i.e 3.5.1 & 4.5.0 respectively.

The current jQuery version used on our site for desktop is 3.1.0 and 2.0.0 for mobile
The current bootstrap version used on our site is Bootstrap v3.3.7 for web & mobile

Our site is a shopping site and as we would be upgrading the jQuery & bootstrap version both, we may encounter some unexpected errors. Also, there are many additional third party plugins used on the site which may fail due to some compatibility issues. We had suggested to the client that the migration process would require us to test each and and every flow and functionality on the site at-least once. Also, device and browser testing would be required. The estimates were provided accordingly.

However, the client is not happy with the estimates and wanted to know if there is any other way out which would reduce the time spent and scope of the testing. Could someone suggest some pointers that would reduce the total amount of time spent and if we could target only specific areas instead of testing the entire application?

The application uses : jQuery, JavaScript, PHP-Laravel, HTML ,CSS